# Xamarin post photo to azure mobile service

Tags: c#, http, post, xamarin, photo

For some reason when i post from my xamarin app i get a 500, using chrome Advanced Rest Client i can post a photo so the service is working (the problem is in the app post)...

My Controller:

```
   public class BlobController : ApiController
    {
        public Task<List<FileDetails>> Post()
        {
            if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent("form-data"))
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
            }

            return FileStorage.StoreFiles(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebApiContainer"], Request);
        }

public class FileDetails
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long Size { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
}
```

My post:

```
public async Task<FileDetails> PostPhotoRequest(string fileName, MemoryStream file)
{
    byte[] response = await _service.PostFileRequest("Blob", fileName, file);
    string json = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response, 0, response.Length);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(json)) { return new FileDetails(); }
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FileDetails>(json);
}


    public async Task<byte[]> PostFileRequest(string url, string filename, MemoryStream file)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var content = new MultipartFormDataContent("boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryGQ9UK82gG8XpzEBT");
        content.Add(new StreamContent(file));
        content.Add(new FormUrlEncodedContent(new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("filename", filename) }));
        content.Headers.Add("X-ZUMO-APPLICATION", Constants.MobileServiceApplicationKey);
        var response = await client.PostAsync(Constants.MobileServiceUrl + "api/" + url, content);
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            byte[] responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
            return responseContent;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

response statuscode: Internal server error

Answer (score 0):

Trying this as a solution.... added Content-type and Content-Disposition

```
public async Task<byte[]> PostFileRequest(string url, string filename, MemoryStream file)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    var streamContent = new StreamContent(file);
    streamContent.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
    streamContent.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
    content.Add(streamContent, "file", filename);
    content.Headers.Add("X-ZUMO-APPLICATION", Constants.MobileServiceApplicationKey);
    var response = await client.PostAsync(Constants.MobileServiceUrl + "api/" + url, content);
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        byte[] responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
        return responseContent;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

since you are getting a 500 error message, 
my suggestion is to first look at the Log from the Azure Portal Dashboard.
It may pinpoint exactly the error, probably an attribute mismatch..